Why can't we use only keys to calculate self-attention?
I was reading about the self-attention mechanism and the paper suggests to have 3 things to be computed: Key, Query and Value. As far as I understood the reason for having Value is to allow adjustments to the initial embedding (after the positional encoding) depending on the context (that's intuitive). However, I don't get why we need the Query there. Why can't we do the similarity calculations using only the Keys?

I remember a student asking this question when I first learned about transformers. The professor responded that while this is possible, empirical performance is better if they are separate.
